# Let quotes filter results in job search title

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, search

## Edit:

I notice that both the word "ios" and "developer" are present in the job description page, so I am making this a feature request, that we can specify the words contained in the title only.

I should note that the fact that those words are mentioned in the description are irrelevant to their meaning (I.E.: the post says "we already have iOS Developers" etc).

## Original:

I searched for a job title with quotes(") around the search term, but already the second result had no words in common:

[image: job search results]

Comment: I can't find any guidelines on the jobs search rules to state if enclosing exact phrases in quotes is supported. It's a pretty common feature with search engines, so it would make sense that it should be supported, but it might just be working as designed. On the other hand, if you're looking for a way to do it without concern of reporting a bug, you could make this a [meta-tag:support] request, and list this as something you've tried to get an exact match.

Comment: @DavyM so you’re saying I should change tag from bug to feature request?